# multi-line plotting in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, multiline

So I want to plot a multi-line plot like this: [image]

Now I am trying to do it myself, but the ethnic groups like White, Black, Asian etc etc are in a column under the heading of "Ethnicity"

This is what my data looks like after filtering from the original dataframe:

```
plt1_data = df1.loc[(df1.Region == "All") & (df1.Age == "All") & (df1.Sex == "All"),["Ethnicity","Value","Time"]]
                       Ethnicity Value  Time
12                           All   4.8  2004
192                        Asian   9.4  2004
372                  Asian Other   9.3  2004
552                        Black  12.8  2004
732                       Indian   6.9  2004
...                          ...   ...   ...
34212  Pakistani and Bangladeshi   8.4  2018
34392                    Unknown   4.1  2018
34572                      White   3.7  2018
34752              White British   3.8  2018
34932                White Other   3.4  2018
```

And this is the code that I am using to get a graph similar to one above:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot( 'Time', 'Ethnicity', data=plt1_data, color='red')
plt.plot( 'Time', 'Ethnicity', data=plt1_data, color='yellow')
plt.plot( 'Time', 'Ethnicity', data=plt1_data, color='magenta')
plt.plot( 'Time', 'Ethnicity', data=plt1_data, color='blue')
plt.legend()
```

But it doesnt work well and gives me the following graph: [image]

So I need help with fixing my graph.
Highly appreciate it!

Update graph: [image]

Code for Update graph:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
for cat, df_cat in plt1_data.groupby('Ethnicity'):
    plt.plot(df_cat['Time'],df_cat['Value'], label=cat)
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=plt1_data, x='Time', y='Value', hue='Ethnicity')
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it gave me this: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to do a "groupby" and to loop over the resulting ethnicities and dataframes

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
for cat, df_cat in plt1_data.groupby('Ethnicity'):
    plt.plot(df_cat['Time'],df_cat['Value'], label=cat)
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! But the graph looks messy. See the graph I attached above

Comment: Looks like the type of your data is not numeric but object. In this case you have to convert it before.